# how to pass indefinite number of boolean arguments ByRef in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a some userform options that I want to make their value false, and for that I need a sub which can receive an indefinite number of boolean arguments and make them all false.

I tried:

```
Sub MakeFalse(ParamArray options())
For I = 0 To UBound(options)
    options(I) = False
Next
End Sub
```

And call it like this:

```
MakeFalse OptionButton1.Value,OptionButton2.Value,OptionButton3.Value,OptionButton5.Value
```

It receives the values but they don't change in the userform

I tried also this:

```
Sub MakeFalse(options() As Boolean)
For I = 0 To UBound(options)
    options(I) = False
Next
End Sub
```

And call it through this:

```
b = Array(OptionButton1.Value,OptionButton2.Value,OptionButton3.Value,OptionButton5.Value)
MakeFalse b
```

But it gives me TypeMismatch Error.

Comment: You're only passing the boolean *value* of the optionbutton control - there is no link between that boolean and the control.  You should pass in the controls themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should be placed in the code sheet of your userform where it should be `Private` because it will not be called from another module.

```
Private Sub MakeFalse(ParamArray Options())

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(Options)
        Me.Controls("OptionButton" & Options(i)).Value = False
    Next
End Sub
```

Call the sub with code like this:-

```
Private Sub TestMakeFalse()
    MakeFalse 1, 2, 3, 5
End Sub
```

Observe that you might pass the controls themselves, like you tried to do but that looks like a lot of redundant typing. The way I suggest, you can make up the control's name just by giving its number and create the object itself in the sub once you have its name.

Comment: Many thanks, I like your brillant suggestion, it is very helpfull

Comment: I tried that to modify .visible property of a group of textboxes like that :

`Me.Controls(Options(i)).Value = False`
but it gives me _"incorrect use of keyword Me"_
and I tried this :
`UserForm1.Controls(Options(i)).Value = False`
but it makes **the whole UserForm invisible**
can you help me please ?

Comment: Use the Visible property not the Value property.

Comment: `Me` specifies the current object. If the object is a user form it's the form, else it's usually the worksheet. In `Controls(Options(i))` "Options(1)" must be a valid control name. The variable Options(1) stands for a string, like `Me.Controls("TextBox1").Visible = False`